# C++ 11 Thread initialization with member functions compiling error

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, c++11, member

I'm just starting to use C++ 11 threads and I've been struggling on a (probably silly) error.
This is my example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  A() {
    cout << "A constructor\n";
  }

  void foo() {
    cout << "I'm foo() and I greet you.\n";
  }

  static void foo2() {
    cout << "I'm foo2() and I am static!\n";
  }

  void operator()() {
    cout << "I'm the operator(). Hi there!\n";
  }
};

void hello1() {
  cout << "Hello from outside class A\n";
}

int main() {
  A obj;
  thread t1(hello1); //  it works
  thread t2(A::foo2); // it works
  thread t3(obj.foo); // error
  thread t4(obj);     // it works

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to start a thread from a pure member function? If it is not, how can I wrap my *foo* function from object *obj* to be able to create such thread?
Thanks in advance!

This is the compiling error:

> thread_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> thread_test.cpp:32:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread()’
>
> thread_test.cpp:32:22: note: candidates are:
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:133:7: note: std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A::*)(), _Args = {}]
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:133:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘’ to ‘void (A::*&&)()’
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:128:5: note: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:128:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘’ to ‘std::thread&&’
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:124:5: note: std::thread::thread()
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:124:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

Comment: Try a simple lambda: `[&](){obj.foo();}`. [Full code here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4Fh1lL$1).

Comment: +1: Small but complete code example and unabridged error message. Just please note that the code snippet formatting here on SO doesn't like tabs (I've fixed this for you in this post).

Comment: Thanks Angew, I'll surely change tabs in future posts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need a callable object taking no parameters, so

```
thread t3(&A::foo, &obj);
```

should do the trick. This has the effect of creating a callable entity which calls `A::foo` on `obj`.

The reason is that a non-static member function of `A` takes an implicit first parameter of type (possibly cv qualified) `A*`. When you call `obj.foo()` you are effectively calling `A::foo(&obj)`. Once you know that, the above incantation makes perfect sense.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'm sorry to have reposted an existing question, I probably miss the right tags. Btw, now it works!

Comment: @Rob013 Glad it helped. Actually, I just realised this is not very well explained in the duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza i understand the point that any member function(non static) will take implicit first parameter of that type(this pointer of that instance). But why doesn't it works if i pass the object as an argument(the way you did for assigning them on threads) for calling any ordinary member function (ex. A::foo(&obj);) Please tell me more on this..any link for this concept will do fine.Thanks..