# c++ std::thread constructor usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, irrlicht

While trying to use std::threads i found myself with this error.

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments 
File: functional
Line:1152
```

After commenting out some lines and such i found that the error comes from the constructor.

I am also using irrlicht therefore the event variable.

Here is the declaration of the thread:

```
t1=new thread((&EventReceiver::KeyInput3),event);
```

The header of  the function:

```
int EventReceiver::KeyInput3(const SEvent& event)
```

Tryed constructing it in various way but none worked.
What should I do in order to get rid of the error?

Comment: You must pass an object of class EventReceiver to thread constructor before other args

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ 11 Thread initialization with member functions compiling error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434492/c-11-thread-initialization-with-member-functions-compiling-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing `KeyInput` is not a static member function, so you need to pass a pointer to an instance of `EventReceiver` first:

```
EventReceiver* p = ...;
std::thread t(&EventReceiver::KeyInput3, p, event);
```

Comment: Small addition: you can pass a pointer to an object, an object, a reference to an object, or a smart pointer to an object.